# Unrecognizable database format vb6?

Tags: database, vb6

I am trying to open up a database to read values and input into a list view. When I open the form containing the database initialization it gives me the error `Unrecognizable database format` and then displays my database location string. This is how I'm connecting to the database right now,

```
Dim dbcasegoods As Database
Dim rscasegoods As Recordset
Dim strdatabase As String

Private Sub Form_Load()
   strdatabase = ("I:\Casegoods\database\ContractCasegoods.mdb")
   Set dbcasegoods = OpenDatabase(strdatabase, False)

End Sub
```

The part that I don't understand is that I've used this method to connect to a database before, in the same project even, and I've used this database today in a different project.

Comment: could you have converted it to a newer format by accident?  what access version is this?  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257780

Comment: its a bit tricky because im working with access 2007 but the project im working on was made well before then. i dont know if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VB6 (aka VB98) only works with certain Access formats (up to Access97 by default, if I recall).  This can be extended to Access 2000/2002 with SP6.

But many of the post Access 2000 versions (at least to 2003) allow you to create MDB in 1997 format because VB6 just wont go away.  The title bar of the DB object window may display the format (e.g. `dbname DataBAse (Access 2000 file format)`).  I dont know how similar the menu will be in 2007, but

**Tools -> ConvertDatabase -> 97 | 2000 | 2002-2003 formats**

allows you to convert to various formats.